# tabbar animation with ColorMatchTabs in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am using ColorMatchTabs pod to animate tabbar but I am getting one issue in it, I want the tabbar in the bottom.

I am getting the tabbar in top not in bottom is there any way to get it in bottom. is there any way to fix it.

```
import UIKit
import ColorMatchTabs. // pod
class ViewController: ColorMatchTabsViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tabViews: ColorTabs!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    colorMatchTabDataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}

class StubContentViewControllersProvider {

   static let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
       let productsViewController = ViewController2()

       let venuesViewController = ViewController2()

       let reviewsViewController = ViewController2()

       let usersViewController = ViewController2()

       return [productsViewController, venuesViewController, reviewsViewController, usersViewController]
   }()
}

extension ViewController: ColorMatchTabsViewControllerDataSource {
 func numberOfItems(inController controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController) -> Int {
       return TabItemsProvider.items.count
   }

   func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, viewControllerAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
       return StubContentViewControllersProvider.viewControllers[index]
   }

   func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, titleAt index: Int) -> String {
       return TabItemsProvider.items[index].title
   }

   func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, iconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
       return TabItemsProvider.items[index].normalImage
   }

   func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, hightlightedIconAt index: Int) -> UIImage {
       return TabItemsProvider.items[index].highlightedImage
   }

   func tabsViewController(_ controller: ColorMatchTabsViewController, tintColorAt index: Int) -> UIColor {
       return TabItemsProvider.items[index].tintColor
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t look like that pod supports a bottom bar. You’ll need to edit the files yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this

```
private extension MenuView {

func layoutNavigationBar() {
    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navigationBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    navigationBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    navigationBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    navigationBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
}

func layoutTabs() {
    tabs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tabs.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tabs.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    tabs.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tabs.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}

func layoutScrollMenu() {
    scrollMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollMenu.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollMenu.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollMenu.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollMenu.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func layoutShadowView() {
    shadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    shadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    shadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    shadowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    shadowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}

func layoutCircleMenu() {
    circleMenuButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    circleMenuButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: PlusButtonButtonOffset).isActive = true
    circleMenuButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
}
```